# Stop tilde and grave acting as deadkeys on French Macbook Pro keyboard (AZERTY)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, internationalization, karabiner

I have a 2015 Macbook Pro running Mojave where internal keyboard is French AZERTY (ISO) type as shown [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794):

[image: Layout]
Pressing *grave* (the key next to return) or *tilde* (<kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd>) act as a dead keys.

Input stops until the next key is pressed in case I want to type `ã`,`ñ`or`õ` after <kbd>~</kbd> or `à`,`è`,`ì`,`ò`,`ù` after <kbd>`</kbd>

Is it possible to map these so they do not act as dead keys - so pressing <kbd>`</kbd> results in output as in line 1 not line 2.

[image: bbedit]

I have tried installing Karabiner and making a script based on their examples but I can't find something to map the key  **to**.

In my test script below (which doesn't work) the "from:{key_code" "backslash" is what *Karabiner-EventViewer* shows when I press <kbd>`</kbd> (which is where <kbd>\</kbd> is on US keyboard).

The "to:{key_code" "51" (or  *grave_accent_and_tilde*) is what *Karabiner-EventViewer* reports for the <kbd><</kbd> key on my keyboard and was just picked as a test.

```
{
  "title": "Convert deadkey ` to a grave (`) (AZERTY)",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Convert deadkey ` to a grave (`) while leaving £ accessible.",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "backslash"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "51",
              "modifiers": [
                "right_option"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've seen various questions asking about [where](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274495/where-is-the-tilde-on-french-and-us-keyboard-layouts) the [keys are](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49236/how-to-type-in-the-tilde-character-with-an-apple-international-keyboard?noredirect=1) or how to [swap](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281405/easy-way-to-remap-non-modifier-keys-on-mac) them but not how to stop dead key acting as such.

Is this possible in any way using Karabiner or otherwise?

I considered changing keyboard layout to UK and then mapping back every single different key to French location but would rather not if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by making a custom layout with [Ukelele](http://software.sil.org/ukelele/).

Duplicate the French layout, then click on the dead keys and choose "change to output."

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I'd add you have to press `alt-gr` to be able to see the dead key `~` in Ukelele.  Save the changes as *.keylayout* to *~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/* then change to use it in *Input Sources*.  Ofc it says all this in the Ukelele documentation.

Comment: I'm trying to answer [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469002/disable-optionkey-symbol-behavior-of-arbitrary-keyboard-layout-in-macos). Could this work there as well? I don't quite understand the instructions here.

Comment: It’s worth a try.  Mac’s use control  and command for menu shortcuts, option may not work.  Ask in the ukelele forum.   https://groups.google.com/g/ukelele-users?pli=1