# Disable Option+Key=Symbol behavior of arbitrary keyboard layout in MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

#### TLDR

I'm looking for a way to disable the <kbd>Option</kbd> + Key = Symbol behaviour of most keyboard layouts (like US and dvorak), but still allow the application to capture those keypresses.

---

#### Ideal solution

Make <kbd>Option</kbd> + Key send exactly that to the application: <kbd>Option</kbd> + Key. Which means, the part where <kbd>Option</kbd> + Key gets turned into a symbol is disabled, while retaining all other behaviours of the layout. This, regardless of the layout that happens to be selected, be it US, dvorak, or any other layout.

---

#### Problem description and attempted solutions so-far

When using the "U.S.", "ABC", "ABC extended", or "dvorak" layouts, <kbd>Option</kbd> + Key gives symbols.

- This is problematic, as in some applications (e.g. VS Code) these cannot *all* be used for keyboard shortcuts. For example, <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> works as a shortcut, but <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> gives `˜` (the issue probably due to it being a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) that is waiting for the second input).

The "Unicode Hex Input" layout does not do symbols. With it, <kbd>Option</kbd> + Key is no longer a problem; the symbols are gone, and the active application can capture the keypresses so the keyboard shortcuts work. Perfect. Or is it?

- It is not. One issue is that "Unicode Hex Input" has qwerty-layout, and an equivalent dvorak layout does not seem to exists. A second issue is that, in this layout, other and common shortcuts no longer universally work. For example, in firefox, word and powerpoint, <kbd>Option</kbd> + Left/Right no longer moves the cursor to the previous/next word. (Although confusingly, VS Code does not suffer from this issue.)

Comment: IMHO all keyboard layouts "just work". This of course doesn't necessarily mean that functionality meets everybody's needs or wishes. It would be more productive to have a question to solve the specific problem like "how to make keybindings in VS Code with Option as modifier key"

Comment: Thanks for your input, @AivarPaalberg. I tried solving that question some time ago, and couldn't get it to work despite a lot of effort. I was glad to have found the unicode layout and to have finally solved the issue... only to find this new mysterious behavior. So I guess my question now is: why do firefox and powerpoint behave distinctly from vscode. And with "just work" I mean, work consistently and identically regardless of the application it's used in.

Comment: In ideal world software from different developers/companies will work consistently and identically. Until then one solution could be using Karabiner Elements to disable unwanted opt+key combinations by setting them to do nothing (or something which is wanted). Something like rule [Map Left Option + E to Nothing](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#left_option_plus_e_to_left_command_left_option_e).

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I'll look into that! I'd prefer a solution that does not require yet another third-party plug-in, but it seems like I have no choice.

Comment: I've tried Karabiner, and I can't get it to work. Most importantly, mapping (in my case) option + n to "nothing", means that the keycode is no longer sent to the application. Meaning, I can no longer use it in any keyboard shortcuts. What I want is for option + n to be sent... just not as `˜`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's not an answer to the exact question. But this is how I got rid of the dead keys, which is what mattered the most to me (as they prevented the use of those <kbd>Option</kbd> + Key in shortcuts):

1. Create new custom layout files. Follow the steps below, or download mine from [here](https://github.com/rwijtvliet/dotfiles/tree/06ae8946f17d2ac27d8333b66e26cc387329ff49/kblayout/undead.bundle/Contents/Resources):

   1. Install Ukelele;
   2. Create a new layout from the currently selected one;
   3. Press and hold <kbd>Option</kbd> (Alt). The offending layer is shown, with the dead keys in red.
   4. Right-click each dead key and "Make Output..". [image]
   5. Save the `.keylayout` file.
2. Make available:

   1. Copy `.keylayout` file into `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`. A symlink doesn't work.
   2. Reboot
   3. Add the layout as input source

And now, it should be available like the undead layouts shown here:

[image]

Bonus:

If you, like me, want to put a specific keyboard layout under a specific keyboard shortcut (instead of just 'switching to the next one'), this is also not possible out of the box. To do that:

1. Create a script that sets the layout
2. Bind a keyboard shortcut to that script. I use `skhd` for that.

[Here](https://github.com/rwijtvliet/dotfiles/tree/1f63fbcdb252fb82dd28bc61126fa7a63441ca50/kblayout) is some information on the whole process.

---

Offtopic proposal to the reader

I won't bitch about my frustration and how much I hate a company that makes things that are so basic so hard. And in return you don't tell me how great and intuitive these apple products are.